# How to change the color of some text in textbox - Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, textbox, colors

I have a usual TextBox. I know in order to change the color of some text I can use Run tag. But when I try to use it imperatively instead declaratively (because I need to do that dynamically) I have the text in TextBox like

```
AAA<Run...>Text to be changed in color</Run>
```

and sure nothing in color changes.
How can I change the color of some text in some program way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you have to use a RichTextBox for that, TextBox only works with plaintext.

Comment: Yes, maybe but Silverlight itself doesn't contain such control.

Comment: The documentation on RichTextBox for use in Silverlight can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx